# checking if a string follows a given pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am still new to javascript and I am trying to validate my form. 
One of my inputs is a text input for an identity number that follows the following pattern: `####XX` where # represents a number and X represents a capital letter from A-Z.

Here is my code so far:

```
var IDnum = document.getElementById('identityNumber').value;
if (  (isNaN(IDnum.charAt(0)))  && (isNaN(IDnum.charAt(1)))&& (isNaN(IDnum.charAt(2))) && (isNaN(IDnum.charAt(3))) && (!isNaN(IDnum.charAt(4))) )
{
    document.getElementById('identityError').style.display = "inline-block";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('identityError').style.display = "none";
}
```

I have tried to google it and have seen some info where they use a RegExp however i have yet to learn anything like that.

With my code above, no matter what i type it, it still validates it. Any ideas what i am doing wrong and if there is a more simple and easier way?

EDIT: after looking to regex and similar answers the following

```
^\d{4}[A-Z]{2}$
```

did not work either

Comment: *X represents a character.* What characters are allowed there?

Comment: Edited the post sorry

Comment: Suggest you learn RegEx. It is very powerful. You can start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Try it **^[0-9]{4,}[A-Z]{1,}**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression to identify whether string has 4 digits before a character.

each `\d` represents a digit, `\d\d\d\d` means 4 digits (alternatively `\d{4}`).

followed by `.` means 4 digits followed by any character.

```js
function isAllowed(str) {
  return str.match(/^\d\d\d\d.$/g) !== null 
}

console.log(isAllowed("1234X"));
console.log(isAllowed("123a"));
console.log(isAllowed("3892#"));
console.log(isAllowed("X"));
```

```
var IDnum = document.getElementById('identityNumber').value;
if (isAllowed(IDnum))
{
    document.getElementById('identityError').style.display = "inline-block";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('identityError').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: when i type in 12345 it validates.

Comment: yeah technically digit is also a char, but use `/\d}{4}[A-Z]/` for that as above answer, but that'll ignore all special chars, check out RegEx docs for more specific cases.

Answer (score 4):

A regular expression *is* the way to go here. Use the pattern `^\d{4}[A-Z]$`:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const { value } = document.querySelector('input');
  if (value.match(/^\d{4}[A-Z]$/)) {
    console.log('OK');
  } else {
    console.log('Bad');
  }
});
```

```html
<input>
<button>submit</button>
```

`^\d{4}[A-Z]$` means:

`^` - Match the start of the string

`\d{4}` - Match a digit character (0 to 9) 4 times

`[A-Z]` - Match a character from A to Z

`$` - Match the end of the string

Comment: The answer you accepted permits inputs like `ABCD1234ABCD`, which probably isn't desirable - you *do* need the `^` and `$` anchors, like in my answer

Comment: yes, thanks @CaptainPerformance, I missed that, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function RegexCheck(str) {
  var pettern = new RegExp('^[0-9]{4,}[A-Z]{1,}');
  return pettern.test(str);
}

console.log(RegexCheck("####X"));
console.log(RegexCheck("1234A"));
console.log(RegexCheck("2C35B"));
console.log(RegexCheck("A698C"));
console.log(RegexCheck("1698b"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#htmlattrdefpattern) to provide a RegExp string:

`^\d{4}[A-Z]{2}$` would be a string consisting of 4 digits followed by two capital letters between `A` and `Z`.

**Explanation**

`^`: Beginning of the string.

`\d{4}`: Exactly 4 digits in a row (this could also be written as `\d\d\d\d`)

`[A-Z]{2}`: Exactly 2 characters from the range of character between `A` and `Z` (alternatively `[A-Z][A-Z]`).

`$`: The end of the string.

```css
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}

input:not(:invalid) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^\d{4}[A-Z]{2}$">
```